# Totalprice doesn't equal to right values JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying once again to create a shop app, just a project to learn some coding & I came over this problem where when I remove a product from the shopping cart it doesn't return the right value

Preview of what i'm trying to create
https://gyazo.com/b4cb34ea65ff311b80ccdb0070404843

Adding the product to the cart function

```
Store.AddProductToCart = (product, price) => {
  Basket.push({
    product: product,
    price: price,
  });

  Store.TotalPrice = 0;

  Basket.forEach(({ price }) => {
    Store.TotalPrice += price;
  });

  console.log(Basket);

  $("span[total]").html(
    `<span style="color: lightgreen">${Store.TotalPrice}kr</span>`
  );

  $(".basket-body").append(`
      <div class="basket-items">
        <ul products>
          <li class="item">${product} - <span style="color: lightgreen">${price}kr</span><button value=${product} data-price=${price} style="float: right" id="remove" class="remove">Radera</button></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  `);
  $(".remove").click(function (e) {
    Store.RemoveProduct();
    Store.Toaster({
      type: "remove",
      text: `Du tog bort en <span style="color: lightcoral">${$(
        this
      ).val()}</span> för <span style="color: lightcoral">${$(this).data(
        "price"
      )}kr</span>`,
    });
    $("span[total]").html(Store.TotalPrice);
  });
};
```

Removing the product function

```
Store.RemoveProduct = () => {
  var $this = $(event.currentTarget),
    cartItem = $this.parent(),
    newPrice = parseFloat($this.data("price"));

  cartItem.remove();
  Store.TotalPrice = Store.TotalPrice - newPrice;
  $("span[total]").text(Store.TotalPrice);
};
```

Hope y'all have a great day/morning/night/evening wherever you are & hope we can solver this problem together!

Peace

Comment: In your ```<ul products>``` should it be ```<ul class="products">```?

Comment: Does ```newPrice``` have the expected value?